# How to place images and texts precisely in one way on a wide screen and in another order on a small screen?

Tags: html, css, responsive, grid-layout

I will need to create a part like this: [screenshot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r17vI.png) in large screen  and this [screenshot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PYCNN.png) in small screen. I tried to do it with "grid .rows-cols" or "grid-items" and I can more or less get what I want on a wide screen, but it does not look good at all on small screen...I think the most important problem that I do not know how to manage is the order of the elements: it is different on the small screen and I do not know how to rearrange them according to the size of the screen .Do you have a solution? Thank you

My code attempts here:

- Attempt with 'grid-container' and 'grid-items':

```
<div class="services section background-white">
                <div class="grid-container">
                    <div class="grid-item titre">
                        <h2 class="services">Nos services</h2>
                    </div>
                    <div class="grid-item img1">
                        <img >
                    </div>
                    <div class="grid-item text1">
                        Cours particuliers
                    </div>
                    <div class="grid-item img2">
                        <img>
                    </div>
                    <div class="grid-item text2">
                        Cours en groupe
                    </div>
                    <div class="grid-item img3">
                        <img >
                    </div>
                    <div class="grid-item text3">
                        Ballade organisée
                    </div>
                    <div class="grid-item img4">
                        <img >
                    </div>
                    <div class="grid-item text4">
                        Conférence en ligne
                    </div>
                    <div class="grid-item para">
                        <p>
                            Nous proposons des cours particuliers et des cours en groupe pour répondre à vos besoins spécifiques. Que vous souhaitiez éduquer votre chiot, résoudre des problèmes de comportement ou simplement renforcer votre lien avec votre animal, nous avons la solution pour vous.
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>


.grid-container{
    display: grid;
}

.titre{
    grid-column: 3 ;
    grid-row: 1;
}

h2.services{
    color: #000 !important;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-bottom: 5%;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 3%;
}

.text1, .text2, .text3, .text4{
    font-weight: bolder;
    font-size: 25px;
    margin-top: 2%;
    margin-bottom: 10%;
}

.img1, .img2, .img3, .img4{
    max-width: 70%;
}

.img1{
    grid-column: 1 ;
    grid-row: 1;
    margin-top: 5%;
}

.text1{
    grid-column: 1 ;
    grid-row: 2;
}

.img2{
    grid-column: 2 ;
    grid-row: 1;
    margin-top: 5%;
}

.text2{
    grid-column: 2 ;
    grid-row: 2;
}

.img3{
    grid-column: 1 ;
    grid-row: 3;
}

.text3{
    grid-column: 1 ;
    grid-row: 4;
}

.img4{
    grid-column: 2 ;
    grid-row: 3;
}

.text4{
    grid-column: 2 ;
    grid-row: 4;
}

.para{
    grid-column: 3 ;
    grid-row: 2 / 4;
    font-size: 20px !important;
}
```

-Attempt with ".rows-cols" :

```
<div class="services section background-white">
                <div class="row container">
                    <div class="col-4 col-sm-5 img1">
                        <img >
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-4 col-sm-5 img2">
                        <img>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-4 col-sm-12 titre">
                        <h2 class="services">Nos services</h2>
                    </div>

                    <div class=" col-4 col-sm-5 text1">
                        Cours particuliers
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-4 col-sm-5  text2">
                        Cours en groupe
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-4  col-sm-10 offset-sm-1 para">
                        <p>
                            Nous proposons des cours particuliers et des cours en groupe pour répondre à vos besoins spécifiques. Que vous souhaitiez éduquer votre chiot, résoudre des problèmes de comportement ou simplement renforcer votre lien avec votre animal, nous avons la solution pour vous.
                        </p>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-4 col-sm-4 img3">
                        <img >
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-4 col-sm-4 img4">
                        <img src="https://animal-mon-ami.fr/wp-content/uploads/2021/04/11838925_957959547579454_2043616677968916251_o-300x199.jpg" >
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-4 col-sm-4"></div>

                    <div class="col-4 col-sm-4 text3">
                        Ballade organisée
                    </div>
                    
                    <div class="col-4 col-sm-4 text4">
                        Conférence en ligne
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: try using media queries in your CSS [link]https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_mediaqueries.asp. there is a lot about them on the internet.

Comment: Your second set of HTML appears to be using bootstrap. Do you want a straight CSS/HTML solution or one using bootstrap? if the latter, please tag it.